# Calculus question - Need a push in the right direction

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve this question:

[image: MATHS]

But I just can't figure out what the first step is, little help? THANKS!

Comment: See [Characteristic equation (calculus)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus))

Comment: ... and [Homogeneous equations with constant coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equations_with_constant_coefficients)

Comment: That $t$ is the number of _hours_, rather than _minutes_, or _years_ or whatever, was not specified in the problem.  That's really sloppy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too specific to be of any future use.

Comment: Please type the question in instead of posting a graphic.  This allows the post to load faster and helps internet searches as well as allows teachers to detect forms of cheating.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, it's possible that the text specified the units of measurement for $t$, but that the OP erased it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have not yet been introduced in a formal way to differential equations, look at it this way.

You know that 
$$f'(t) =-0.2f(t)$$
and want to find $f(t)$.

Can you think of a function (other than the identically $0$ function)  whose derivative is (always) $-0.2$ times the function?

Maybe not!  But you have certainly met a function whose derivative is the function itself.

Let $g(t)=e^t$.  Then $g'(t)=e^t$.  More generally, if $g(t)=Ce^t$, where $C$ is a constant, then $g'(t)=g(t)$.

So $e^t$ sort of behaves like you want, except for the $-0.2$ part.  Can you think of a way of modifying $e^t$ so that when you differentiate, the right constant will appear in front?

It would be best to think about this for a while by yourself, but

**Hint**:  What happens when you differentiate $e^{kt}$, or more generally $Ce^{kt}$?

Comment: Ah! That actually makes a lot of sense. So -0.2 is k, right? So to find the suger remaining I'd solve for S-not in: 100=e^(-0.2*5)*S-not? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @InBetween: The **general** solution is $Ce^{-0.2t}$. At time $t=0$ there are $100$ grams, so $C=100$.  To find sugar remaining after $5$ hours, substitute $t=5$ in $100e^{-0.2t}$, then use calculator.  To find $t$ so that $1$ gram is left, solve $1=100e^{-0.2t}$ for $t$.  To do that, take the logarithm of both sides, although to avoid negatives I would probably first rewrite as $100=e^{0.2t}$.  One needs some facility with basic facts about logarithms.

Comment: @InBetween: Whatever you get as your answer to the $1$ gram question, you can check by plugging into the formula. By the way, you should get a bit over $23$ hours.

Answer (score 4):

What you have is an initial value problem: a differential equation with a particular value:
$$\frac{df}{dt} = -0.2f,\qquad f(0)=100g.$$
To start, you need to solve for $f$. This is a separable equation, so just separate:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{df}{dt} &= -0.2f\\
\frac{df}{f} &= -0.2\,dt.
\end{align*}$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

If $f'(t)$ were equal to $f(t)$ what woud it be? If $f'(t)$ were equal to $-f(t)$ what  woud it be? Your case is a generalization. I describe the standard approach.

Your equation can be rewritten as $y'+0.2y=0$, where $y=f(t)$. This is a [homogeneous equation with constant coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equations_with_constant_coefficients). The standard method to solve it is by finding the roots of the [caracteristic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_%28calculus%29). In this case this equation is $X+0.2=0$. Since $X=-0.2$, the general solution is $y=Ae^{-0.2t}$. The initial condition $f(0)=100$ gives $A=100$. Thus $y=f(t)=100e^{-0.2t}$.

Let's confirm: $y=f(t)=100e^{-0.2t}$, $y'=f'(t)=100(-0.2)e^{-0.2t}=-20e^{-0.2t}$. We do have $-20e^{-0.2t}+0.2\cdot 100e^{-0.2t}\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation can be changed to $f' + 0.2 f = 0$, a homogeneous linear differential equation with constant coefficients. Try to write a polynomial whose roots will help you find a solution to your problem.